# Why do we need a minimum voltage here?

Tags: diodes, voltage-source

Let's assume we have a circuit like this: (Us should be monopolar but I didn't find something like that).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJUFk3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Negative half wave: D2 is active -> output voltage = -0.7V
positive half wave: D1 is active -> output voltage = ?

Well.. I know that we have 5.7V output here but my problem is that I don't get why we **need** 5.7V at least here by Uin. I would assume that as we have a source here we don't need any other input. So our U in only controls which output gets active.

Comment: Tim, I took the liberty of fixing your schematic. The convention is that higher voltages go to the top of the page (so I re-oriented Us) and GND symbols always point down (to the ground, as it were).

Answer (score 3):

This looks like an input protection circuit. The diodes prevent the voltage at \$V_{OUT}\$ from being higher than \$V_{DD}+0.7V\$ or being lower than \$-0.7V\$. The resistor is there to limit the current passing through the diodes.

Comment: I agree, an ESD input protection circuit that nearly all ICs have looks similar to this but then there will also be two diodes at the node between Uin and R1. The function of an ESD protection circuit is to limit (clamp) the voltage Uout to the values mentioned in this answer.

Comment: My problem is that I would expect that the D1 part gets active once we reach 0.7V. Why do we need 5.7V? Or in other words why do we need to supply our second source? This is kind of confusing.

Comment: The diode is forward biased when the anode is 0.7 V above the cathode. If the cathode is at 5 V (because of Us), this doesn't happen until the anode reaches 5.7 V.

Comment: @TimSch You are not **supplying** the second source at 5.7V. There is an existing 5V supply for the electronics being protected. Your \$V_{IN}\$ is some signal coming from the outside world into the protected device.